# Cómo generar Paneles o listas dinámicas?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quiero generar panales con su head, body y footer de manera dinámica, lo único que se es como generar las tablas de esa forma:

```
Function fnDTSECTOR()
    {
        global $AMBIENTE;
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM VSECTOR";
        $CONEXION = fnConexionCRMfbdomingodn($AMBIENTE);
        $RESULTADO = sqlsrv_query($CONEXION,$SQL);
        $TABLE = "<table id='dtSector' class='table table-striped table-bordered' style='width:100%'>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<thead>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; display: none;'>ID</th>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem;'>Sector</th>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem;'>Acciones</th>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</thead>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tbody>\n";
        while($REGISTROS = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RESULTADO))
        {
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n";
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style='font-size:1.1rem; display: none;'>".$REGISTROS["ID"]."</td>\n";
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style='font-size:1.1rem; vertical-align: middle;'>".$REGISTROS["SECTOR"]."</td>\n";
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td align='center'>"."<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' href='#editSector' id='btnActSector'>Actualizar</button>"."<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' href='#inacSector' id='btnDesacSector'>Desactivar</button>"."</td>\n";
        }
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tbody>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n";
        fnDesconexion($CONEXION);

        RETURN $TABLE;
    }
```

Alguien tiene un ejemplo de algún caso o como debo comenzar para generar Paneles o algo similar para hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No deberias usar php para eso, deberias usar angular, angular es mucho mejor considerando la seguridad (lo digo porque nunca es bueno requerir del lado del servidor código html), aunque si no deseas usar angular, la otra opcion es en vez de crear el html en el php para enviarselo al frontend, tener templates de tus html que quieres generar dinamicamente, y lo unico que tendrias que hacer desde el backend es requerir esta información para posteriormente insertar una nueva plantilla de esa tabla y llenarla de información desde el frontend con los datos recibidos por el backend.

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo aún mas dinamico puedes usar ajax, que no recarga la pagina, si deseas un ejemplo de esto ya en breves coloco una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario y muy bien recibido @Riven si me ayudaría mucho un ejemplo usando Ajax. Y para resolver la duda principal, que me sugieres para contruir de manera dinamica paneles, o box, o list, para hacer algo similar a la imagen que coloqué de forma automática. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo del template, supon que este es el template que tienes pensado agregar cada vez que logres obtener de manera exitosa datos de una base de datos:

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Esos datos estan hardcodeados, pero con ayuda de algo llamado `template strings` puedes hacer que lo que sea que quieras que este en alguna parte se renderice ahí, es decir, mira el mismo html pero con template strings:

```js
const firstName = "Jill";
const lastName = "Smith";
const age = 50;

const firstName2 = "Eve";
const lastName2 = "Jackson";
const age2 = 94;

const templateString = 
`
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>${firstName}</td>
      <td>${lastName}</td>
      <td>${age}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>${firstName2}</td>
      <td>${lastName2}</td>
      <td>${age2}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
`;

document.body.innerHTML += templateString;
```

Como vemos, ya los valores dentro de nuestro template html no son hardcodeados, si no que dependen de variables.

Ahora bien, esto de tener en una constante como tal nuestro template no nos sirve, ya que necesitamos que dependa de unas variables, y no todo el tiempo nosotros vamos a tener disponibles estas variables (si cargas información desde una base de datos no los vas a tener disponibles antes).

Así que para poder ayudar a nuestro template a que sea lo mas dinamico posible, encerremoslo en una función que nos devuelva un template con los datos que le pasemos ya inyectados en el template:

```js
function giveMeTheTemplate(firstName, ...parameters){

  return `
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>${firstName}</td>
        <td>${parameters[0]}</td>
        <td>${parameters[1]}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>${parameters[2]}</td>
        <td>${parameters[3]}</td>
        <td>${parameters[4]}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `;

}

document.body.innerHTML += giveMeTheTemplate("Jill", "Smith", 50, "Eve", "Jackson", 94);
```

Con esto ya podemos poner datos dinamicos en cualquier momento en un template y que se nos devuelva el template ya renderizado con los datos.

Ahora, referente a como podemos usar junto con ajax oara que la info sea dinamica, es decir primero cargar los datos mediante ajax y luego meterlos en un template para renderizarlos en nuestro html, lo unico que habría que hacer es primero obtener los datos desde la base de datos, luego ponerselos al template, obtener el template y luego añadir este template a nuestro DOM.

Entonces aquí un ejemplo sencillo de una petición `ajax` sin usar jQuery (jQuery tiene su versión de ajax que es mucho mas pequeña):

```js
const server = "/enviar.php";

function ajax(data, server, method = "POST", responseType = "application/json"){

    return new Promise((res, rej) =>{

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const dataToSend = new FormData();
        xhr.responseType = responseType;

        for(let prop in data){
            dataToSend.append(prop, data[prop]);
        }

        xhr.onload = ()=>{
            res(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        }

        xhr.onerror = e =>{
            rej(e);
        }

        xhr.open(method, server);
        xhr.send(dataToSend);

    });
}

ajax({nombre: "Bill", apellido: "Gates", edad: 65}, server)
.then(res =>{
  //Nuestros datos cargados por el servidor en formato JSON
  const json = JSON.parse(res);
  
  //Aquí ejecutarias la función de tu template y le pasarias los datos
  //Por ejemplo pasarias json.nombre, json.apellido, json.edad
}).catch(e =>{
  //En caso de error no renderizar ni añadir contenido html.
  console.error(e);
})
```

No explicare a fondo ajax, ya que hay muchas partes donde se puede consultar el funcionamiento de ajax, pero en resumen lo que debes tener en cuenta es que en el ejemplo de arriba, como fue usado el metodo `POST` para enviar datos, en tu PHP deberas recibirlos con post, con esas claves, en nuestro caso nombre, apellido y edad, la variable `$_POST` en php es aquella que contiene estos datos a manera de array asociativo, entonces supongamos que le enviamos esos datos a un archivo llamado enviar.php, se recibirian los datos de esa petición ajax así:

```
<?php

   //Sirve para que la respuesta sea códificada y enviada como json en utf-8.
   header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

   $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
   $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
   $edad = $_POST['edad'];

   //Muy sencillo, pero recuerda que debes enviar una respuesta al frontend:
   echo json_encode(["nombre" => $nombre, "apellido" => $apellido, "edad" => $edad]);
?>
```

En este ejemplo se estan enviando y recibiendo los mismos datos por parte del backend ya que no estamos conectando a una BD, pero supongamos que tu quieres enviar esta información al backend para obtener información diferente acerca de tu base de datos, entonces no habría problema, simplemente en vez de codificar los datos que enviaste al backend como json, codificas los que quieras obtener de tu base de datos usando los que recibiste del frontend.

Comment: Ojo otra cosa, cuando dije que angular es mucho mejor para hacer estas cosas no me refiero a que angular sea mejor que php o que php sea inseguro, (aunque me gusta mucho), si no que lo que me refiero es que para este tipo especifico de cosas (hacer paginas web dinamicas), usar html templates es mas seguro por parte de angular y ademas angular en general es mejor para este proposito (templates html dinamicos) pero angular es del lado del cliente si o si aunque uses angular deberas usar algo del lado del backend, y php si lo recomiendo junto con angular, pero solo para su proposito.

Comment: Y el proposito de php en ese caso si usaras angular no seria enviarte al frontend los html directamente, si no solo los datos que requieras de una base de datos, y angular se encarga de lo que querias usar con php (renderizar datos en un html dinamicamente de manera eficaz y poderosa).